# Flutter CheckboxListTile icon border color change

Tags: flutter, colors, checkboxlist

In flutter, CheckboxListTile widget ,i can't change this default color. How can I change it to my desire color. [image]

I want ti customized this border color, how can i chane the border color. I only see the parameters of Checkcolor and some others that can't change default border color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use fillColor property for this output which takes MaterialStateProperty like bellow:

```
fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation **CheckboxListTile** has a side property that simply accepts BorderSide you can use to change its color

Example from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html):

```
CheckboxListTile(side: BorderSide(color:Colors.red) ....
```

> side → BorderSide? The color and width of the checkbox's border.

You can also change color based on state.

```
side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                  return const BorderSide(color: Colors.red);
                }
                return const BorderSide(color: Colors.green);
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkColor: Colors.red,
```

You can change the color with this.